# @meforma/vue-toaster clear function only works when pulled into local project folder, not from node_modules

Tags: vuejs3, vite

As stated, the package `@meforma/vue-toaster` has a `clear()` function in the [API here](https://github.com/MeForma/vue-toaster/blob/master/src/api.js#L14).

My vue and vite project setup:

**main.js**

```
import Toaster from '@meforma/vue-toaster'

app.use(Toaster, {
  position: 'top',
  useDefaultCss: false,
  pauseOnHover: false
}).provide('toast', app.config.globalProperties.$toast)
```

**Example.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="view">
    <div class="mt-10 flex gap-5">
      <button class="btn btn-stealth" @click="showToast('default')">Default</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="showToast('primary')">Primary</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success" @click="showToast('success')">Success</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info" @click="showToast('info')">Info</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="showToast('warning')">Warning</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="showToast('error')">Error</button>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-10">
      <button class="btn" @click="toast.clear">Clear Toasts</button>
      <br><br>
      <button class="btn" @click="clearToasts">Timeout Clear</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { inject } from 'vue'

const toast = inject('toast')

// this works
function showToast (type) {
  toast.show(`This is the ${type} type toast.`, {
    type: type,
    duration: false
  })
}

// only works when vue-toaster is local in my projects src folder :S
function clearToasts () {
  toast.clear()
}
</script>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --open",
    "build": "vite build --out-dir dist",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@meforma/vue-toaster": "^1.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.2.4",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "axios-auth-refresh": "^3.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "microtip": "^0.2.2",
    "pinia": "^2.0.13",
    "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^1.5.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.9",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-meta": "^3.0.0-alpha.10",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.0",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.3.1",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^6.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.6.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.7",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "vite": "^2.8.6"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "@vue/standard"
    ],
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

But, when I pull the package into the local `src` folder and import it via there, the clear works perfectly. No code changes other than moving where the code lives.

I have absolutely no idea why this is the case, if anyone has ever seen anything similar, it would be greatly appreciated.

I looked through all the code of the [project github](https://github.com/MeForma/vue-toaster) and created an issue there.

I thought it might be something to do with the event bus, but then again, it works when pulled from `node_modules` so hence why this is such a head scratcher for me.

Thanks!

---

### Edit 1:

Updated code example that you can run locally to experience the same issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-toaster-test-forked-m64htx?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:854-868

Specifically in the `main.js`, swapping where the `vue-toaster` is pulled in from causes the clear function to stop/start working. Clearing works when `vue-toaster` is located within my project `/src` but fails to work when pulled in from `node_modules`.

### Edit 2:

Here is a stackblitz showing the same issue (using vite too): https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-uqcdgd?file=src%2Fmain.js,src%2FApp.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after [forking @meforma/vue-toaster](https://github.com/shanehoban/vue-toaster), rewriting the Toaster in the composition API and changing the event bus to use `mitt`, even went as far as to [publish it to npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shanehoban/vue-toaster) so I could replicate everything as close as possible to how I use the package originally.... it turns out that my re-written package was having the exact same issue with Vite.

Digging in further, I noticed in my `/node_modules/` there was a folder: `/node_modules/.vite/deps/` which had files like: `@shanehoban_vue-toaster.js`... so I started googling and found out that perhaps I should exclude the package from Vite optimizations... like so:

**vite.config.js**

```
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      "@meforma/vue-toaster"
    ]
  },
  ....
```

And now, the clear... is working.

Comment: The reason is Vite caches the event-bus.js but not the `Toaster.vue`. So the `Toaster.vue` will use an independent event bus instance. I raised an [issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8158) about it

Comment: Thank you @Duannx, I'll award you the bounty as you have been so helpful, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The original answer is a misunderstanding. So I edited it to follow the point of the question.

#### Problem

- The package does NOT work when using it from `node_modules`.
- The package does work when folks it into the project and use it directly

#### Reason

Vite only caches JS files from the package. We can see it in `node_modules/.vite/deps/@meforma_vue-toaster.js`

```js
// The .vue file is point to original file
// node_modules/@meforma/vue-toaster/src/index.js
import Toaster2 from "/Users/admin/Work/test-projects/vite-demo-vue-plugin/node_modules/@meforma/vue-toaster/src/Toaster.vue";

// node_modules/@meforma/vue-toaster/src/api.js
import Toaster from "/Users/admin/Work/test-projects/vite-demo-vue-plugin/node_modules/@meforma/vue-toaster/src/Toaster.vue";

// The js file is cached here so Singleton pattern will breaks
// node_modules/@meforma/vue-toaster/src/helpers/event-bus.js
var Event = class {
  constructor() {
    this.queue = {};
  }
...
}
```

The event-bus.js is cached in the `.vite` folder but the `Toaster.vue` file is not. So when the `Toaster.vue` uses the `EventBus`, it will call the instance from `node_modules/@meforma/vue-toaster/` instead of the one in the `.vite` cached folder. And it breaks the Singleton pattern of the original package.

This bug might happen to any package with uncachable files mixed with JS files.

#### Workaround

This bug can be fixed only from the Vite side. So before Vite fixes it we need to exclude the package from the Vite cache as [shanehoban's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72220205/4254681) points out:

```js
// vite.config.js

export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      "@meforma/vue-toaster"
    ]
  },
  ....
```

[Github issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/8158)

Comment: Thanks @Duannx, however this doesn't actually solve the issue for me as I am using the `setup` inline. I can't find an online code playground that will run this in the browser, but if you copy it locally it does: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-toaster-test-forked-m64htx?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:854-868 . So locally for me, if I pull the vue-toaster locally, the clears work, however when pulled in via `node_modules` they do not. Very confusing/frustrating

Comment: @shanehoban I did test the package locally with script setup and see the same result with the online demo. I changed the codesandbox to script setup style and see that the behavior is still the same. You can see it on the link I provide above. Note that the function on script setup does not work because some bugs come from the codesandbox itself. But the `onMounted` hook does work and the code gives the same result

Comment: Thanks again @Duannx, but in your `main.js`, does it still work if you import from `node_modules`? Change your import to: `import Toaster from '@meforma/vue-toaster'`. The issue was that I can get it to clear when importing locally, but not from `node_modules`. Thanks again for looking into this!

Comment: @shanehoban It does work. I changed to use the package from npm. There is no difference

Comment: I tried again, but this still doesn't work for me, unless it is outside of my `node_modules`. The only difference between your code sandbox that I can see is that I am using `vite` as my development server, as opposed to `vue cli`... could this somehow be the reason? I just forked your sandbox as it might be the easiest way to share my full package.json: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-toaster-test-forked-oiphrk?file=/package.json

Comment: It's tough to help if the problem persists only in your local. https://stackblitz.com/?starters=vite has a template with Vite. Please try to reproduce your problem in there

Comment: ah I see, here it is: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-uqcdgd?file=src%2Fmain.js,src%2FApp.vue

Comment: Faced same issue not able to get it to work even after exclude step.